# How to insert image in Toolbar in Appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building an app with appcelerator studio for Android system.
So I want to display and customize a ToolBar.
So this is my index.xml layout:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <ActionBar id="actionbar" title="" icon="/images/logo_decipher.png"  />
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem id="item1" title="Settings"  />
            <MenuItem id="item2" title="Search" />
        </Menu>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

I want to display my personal Image in this Toolbar. I'm try to use tag icon but not works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use actionbarExtras. https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/actionbarextras/blob/master/documentation/index.md

Ray